# Overlapping lines ggplot2 in x axis...jitter not making any good results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been all day looking on the questions for help. But the answers doesn't serve on my purpose (or I am not able to accomplish that).

Well, I'm doing a line chart with ggplot2 to compare some variables, but this variables are linear and remain constant in the same y-position. Two of them overlap and I'm not able to stack them. I've tried dodge_position, but it moves aside the lines; I've tried `position="stack"` but it does 
separate too much the lines and I've tried jitter but the effect is not a working solution.

Jitter

[image: jitter]

Stack

[image: stack]

Dodge_Position

[image: dodge]

This is the code I've been using:

```
ggplot(aa, aes(x=Time, y=measurement, colour = condition)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title='Title', x='Time', y='Var', colour="Condition") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold",vjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold")) 


 #####With Position Jitter###
geom_line(position=position_jitter(h=0.003))

#####With Position Dodge###
geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=50))

####With Position Stack####
geom_line(position="stack")
```

Is there a way to stack the lines with a minimum distance, like in this image?

[image: a]

EDIT: Using dput, I obtain this (http://www.beetxt.com/s95/).

Comment: Please can you include some data (use `dput`) to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I've added  the dput output i get at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about jittering the data by each group. Something like this

```
jit <- 0.1
aa$measurement2 <- unlist(
  tapply(aa$measurement, aa$condition, function(x){
    x + runif(1,-jit, jit)
}))

ggplot(aa, aes(x=Time, y=measurement2, colour = condition)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title='Title', x='Time', y='Var', colour="Condition") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold",vjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"))
```

To use a fixed offset rather than a random offset, use something like

```
aa$measurement2 <- aa$measurement + c(-0.05, -0.05, 0.05, 0.05)[ as.factor(aa$condition)]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your help! That is really close to what I'm looking for... is there a possibility of getting those lines even closer (To y=4 and y=3.5) ?

Comment: Either reduce `jit` or explicitly set the value for each condition

Comment: How can I set explicitly the value for the conditions? (Excuse me if that's an obvious procedure, first time on R).